# Match generates "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Tags: excel, vba, text, number-formatting

I want to create a database. It seems VBA won't recognize numbers.

This is the error I get:

> Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class

[image: this is the error I get]

This is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TargetRow As Integer

TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnB_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Onsite_Number"), 0)
MsgBox TargetRow

End Sub
```

This is a picture of my worksheet:
[image: This is a picture of my worksheet]

Onsite Number = ColumnB_Menu

Comment: That error means that no match was found. What are `ColumnB_Menu` and  `.Range("Dyn_Onsite_Number")`? i.e. what is the specific value of `ColumnB_Menu` when this fails?

Answer (score 0):

Late Bind the Match by removing `WorkSheetFUnction.` and test for the error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim TargetRow As Variant

    TargetRow = Application.Match(ColumnB_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Onsite_Number"), 0)

    If Not IsError(TargetRow) Then
        MsgBox TargetRow
    Else
        MsgBox ColumnB_Menu & " Not Found in Range"
    End If

End Sub
```